# curl output file permission. How to set it while creating

Tags: html, apache, curl, static, cron

I am trying to generate static html files by scheduling curl command in cron which is accessing a url. like:

```
00 6 * * * /usr/bin/curl -m 14400 -o /opt/lampp/htdocs/reports/fragtab32595849.html http://xx.xx.xx.xx/fragtables.php?db=32595849
```

here /opt/lampp/htdocs/reports/fragtab32595849.html is the output file generated to an apache root directory. so that this static page is available for offline.

I am doing this because http://xx.xx.xx.xx/fragtables.php code execution take almost half an hour to analyses all oracle tables.

everything works fine except, the file generated is having permissions like

```
-rw-r-----  1 oracle oinstall 46357 Aug 15 06:13 fragtab32595849.html
```

since this file is not readable by everyone, Apache is not able to serve it.
if i manually change the permission using chmod to:

```
-rw-r--r--
```

then apache start serving the page.
I am looking for a solution how to instruct curl to generate file with desired permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify `crontab` line to

```
00 6 * * * /usr/bin/curl -m 14400 -o /opt/lampp/htdocs/reports/fragtab32595849.html http://xx.xx.xx.xx/fragtables.php?db=32595849 && chmod o+x /opt/lampp/htdocs/reports/fragtab32595849.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it indirectly via a script that sets a more permissive umask before invoking curl.

Comment: A wrapper script is something i also thought about. with a umask within that script. thats my last resort. 
as you see in my question the php file is accepting the a parameter. i think the wrapper script also should accept that as parameter and pass it to curl